# socket.io is not refreshing data

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I am trying to display filesize on with socket.io with every time file changes. Here is my js code.

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendfile('index.html');
});
var fs = require("fs");
var filesize;
var filename = 'D:\\test.txt';

fs.watchFile(filename, function() {
    fs.open(filename, 'r', function(err, fd) {
        fs.stat(filename, function(err, stat) {
            if(err) { console.log('error');  }
            console.log(stat.size);
            filesize = stat.size;
        });
    })
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('A user connected');
    socket.emit('testerEvent', { description: prntarr});
    socket.on('clientEvent', function(data){
        console.log(data);
    });
    socket.on('disconnect', function () {
        console.log('A user disconnected');
    });

});

http.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('listening on localhost:3000');
});
```

The problem is , socket is not refreshing data but console shows changed size. It refreshes only when i reload the page. Please suggest where i am making mistake and how to fix it.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You need to do a `socket.emit()` inside your `fs.watchFile()` callback. You're not emitting anything when the file changes at the moment

---

- When a user connects, push his `socket` in an Array.
- Inside the `watchFile` callback, iterate through the connected sockets Array and `.emit()` what you want to send.
- Don't forget to remove from that
  Array any `sockets` that have disconnected

Comment: it worked. i moved io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('A user connected'); before fs.watchfile and added socket.emit() inside. Thanks